# Opening files by relative path on Windows using C

Tags: c, windows, file

I have this file/folder structure:

```
root
 out
   test1
    test1.exe
   test2
    test2.exe
   test3
    test3.exe
 bin
  run_test.exe
```

I would like to run all the test executables (test1, test2, etc.) which are found in subfolders of `out` folder consecutively from the `run_test.exe` executable.

In my `run_test.exe` code, I can get the working directory of the executable `run_test.exe` by using `GetModuleFileName()` function from Windows API. My question is how can I execute (or trigger) test executables from run_test code? Should I navigate to each executable folder or can I do it using relative directory changes?

Comment: You must provide a path that "finds" the executable. So a relative path from your current executable works, an absolute path will work, or navigating to the directory and only providing the executable name will work. In all cases: just write a test program and find out for yourself.

Comment: But how? I have the absolute path of run_test.exe in my path variable thanks to GetModuleFileName(0, path, PATH_BUFFER_CAP - 1) function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on where the current working directory needs to be when you run each of the test executables. What I would do is use `GetModuleFileName` to get the location of the executable, then chop off the name of the exe and the `bin` to get the root directory as an absolute path.

Each executable name can be created by then concatenating the root directorty with (for example) `"out\\test1\\test1.exe"`

If you need to set the current directory to the test directory, just concatenate `"out\\test1"` to the root directory and use [SetCurrentDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365530(v=vs.85).aspx) to set the current working directoy. Then you can run the executable with just its name e.g. `test1.exe`

Answer (score 1):

You could navigate back from your bin directory. Generally everything that can be used in command will work. Try using [dirent.h.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/dirent.h.html) There you can get the subfolders of your out folder and loop them, parsing commands for the run of each test using a simple sprintf.

Comment: The question is tagged Windows.